# Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework

I have read the code first migration from msdn.But in case If my database team changes data base i.e. If some one add/update/delete some fields from a table how to migrate that changes?

I mean How my code first model update that change?

Please help me.I am using Entity Framework 6.1.

Comment: If you have a database team, Migrations is likely not for you. You can still use "Code First" to map your entities to an existing database but turn off Migrations. If the schema changes, you'll have to update your entities and mappings.

Comment: Should I do it manually?

Comment: you took a wrong option, if your database creation / edit will be handled from database, you should use database first approach, code first migration is meant to apply the changes (and provide upgrade script, etc) from code to database..

Comment: @YuliamChandra Not necessarily. "Code First" works perfectly fine for mapping entities to separately-managed databases. Code First can be used without Migrations. If you want to use an EDMX designer, use DB First; if you want to use code to perform mappings, use Code First.

Comment: @AnthonyChu, but still the wrong option imho, you will end up having so much effort to use code first for existing database, even using generation / reverse engineering tool, I used code first to map [existing database of ppdm_model](http://www.ppdm.org/ppdm-standards/ppdm-3-8-data-model), then we ended up regretting it cause it took more effor then just "right click and update from database"..

Comment: @YuliamChandra I think it's a personal decision that's dependent on the situation/team/etc. I find that DB first tends to encourage entities that mirror the database schema; and it makes it difficult to add behavior to the entities (need to use partial classes) and to separate the entities from EF. Those who want to take a more DDD and Onion/Hexagonal architecture approach will want entities that are designed for the domain, separated from the persistence layer, and contain logic in addition to data. DB first adds too much friction and Code First is often preferred in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your problem because the real purpose of migration is Update Database changing fields or tables. You just need to launch:

add-migration NameOfMigration
and
Update-Database.
in package manager console.

As you can see in the migration called "NameOfMigration" that is created you have 2 different method: Up and Down. This allow you to Update your database with that changes (up) or come back (down).